# Customize shipping price calculation in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've got the following scenario:

1. Regular category
2. Sales category

I will sort countries by zone to make the explanation easy:

1. Lebanon, zone A
2. (some countries), zone B
3. (all remaining countries), zone C

Shipping is based on the total purchased amount, and not on weight, so the conditions to calculate the shipping cost are the following:

- If shipping in Lebanon, the category is not "sales" and the price is below 50$, then 3$, otherwise free shipping.
- If shipping in zone B, the category is not "sales" and the price is below 100$, then 15$, otherwise free shipping.
- If shipping in zone C, the category is not "sales" and the price is between 0$ and 149$, then 50$, otherwise if the price is between 150$ and 199$, then 30$, else free shipping.

What is the best practice to implement this kind of shipping prices in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step-by-step guide:-

– Go to System –> Configuration –> SALES –> Shipping Methods –> Table Rates
– Select ‘Enabled‘ to ‘Yes’
– Click the ‘Save Config‘ present in top right corner of the page
– From the ‘Current Configuration Scope‘ (which is at the top left corner), choose ‘Main Website‘

Now, you will see as in the following figure:-

Tablerates Configuration

[image: magento table rates]
As you can see from the figure, there are three main parts:- Condition, Export and Import.

– As we are making different shipping rate for different country, so select Condition = ‘Price vs. Destination’
– Click ‘Export CSV‘ and a csv file is downloaded with the required headers like country, region, shipping price, etc.
– Fill the csv with the shipping rate and country name. For example, see the following figure:-
[image: table rates csv figure]
Tablerates CSV

– The asterik (*) in region and postal code column means that the shipping price is applicable for all regions and postal code respectively.
– The zero (0) in order subtotal means that the shipping price is applicable for all orders whose subtotal is greater than zero.
– In the last row (7th row), you can see ‘AK’ as region. Hence, comparing the 2nd row and 7th row where the country is USA, we see that the shipping price for all other US region is 10. But, the shipping price for AK (Alaska) is 15.

– Now, Import the csv you just filled.
– Click ‘Save Config‘ button present in top right corner of the page.
– You are done. The new country specific shipping rate has been saved. You can test it by checking out products from frontend.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Thank you for your reply i did that but it adding a discount and not regulate shipping cost or didn't get the ability to if sales switch into another shipping method, could you help ?

in more details my rule is for normal product if zone a we got free shipping or have 2$ instead of 3$ on top of 50$ purchase

how can i prevent a sales to go and have the normal shipping cost that is 3$ for example

Comment: These are already done and it covers the basics however i installed talbematrix where it have more options but the problem is sales category have their own pricing and normal once have the same and we do need to integrate these together when their products added from both categories and give the accurate shipping